# What am I able to (not) include in a .cpp file?

Tags: c++, include, header-files

This question is pretty weird.
Say I have a file, called idiot.cpp, and it begins with:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include "idiot.h"
```

and I have a header file, idiot.h. First of all, in idiot.h, do I also have to insert

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
```

or do I not?
Second, if I have another source file, say, "bonito.cpp," that uses idiot.h, should I just `#include "idiot.h"`, or should I paste in the code snippet again?
If not, is there any way to shorten this so I don't end up including around 20 headers per file? (hypothetically)
Sorry if this is a pretty dumb question, but I don't use many headers too often.

Comment: if idiot.h requires the above headers, as in it cannot be compiled without them, then idiot.h should include the headers. If not, then they are implementation details of the cpp file and no other cpp file should have to include the other headers unless they also need the declarations and definitions contained within.

Comment: Put whatever needs to be in the header so that the declarations in the header succeed. Include in your .cpp file whatever you need that _isn't specified in the corresponding header._

Comment: Don't include what is not needed.  An `.h` file should include only the bare minimum it needs for the things it actually uses.  A `.cpp` file should include only the additional headers it needs that are not already included by other headers it includes.

Comment: awesome, thanks! That does make sense now that I think about it lol, like why I'm not including X11 and a million other things when I include SDL2.h.

Comment: `idiot.cpp` just needs `idiot.h`, colorful names you got there.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would go so far as to say it should include anything it uses that isn't included by its corresponding header file. If `foo.cpp` needs `<vector>` and `<string>`, and `foo.hpp` includes `<vector>`, and `foo.cpp` includes `bar.hpp` which includes `<string>`, then `foo.cpp` should include `<string>` but not `<vector>`. Otherwise it is depending on the details of `bar.hpp` to provide `<string>`, which could change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`idiot.cpp` does not need to include anything included indirectly by `idiot.h` to be able to compile.

The more interesting case: `bonito.cpp` `#include`s `idiot.h` and `idiot.h` includes `x.h`.  If `idiot.h` *only* uses the content of `x.h` for private or anonymous namespace code - and `bonito.cpp` wants to use something from `x.h` too, then `bonito.cpp` should include `x.h` directly (redundantly).

The justification is simple: `idiot.h` can't remove something from the public/protected interface without risking breaking client code, so if that happens then the clients have to expect to deal with it - possibly including an extra header too.  BUT, the maintainer of `idiot.h` and `idiot.cpp` should be free to change private or anonymous namespace content within `idiot.h` without risking breaking client code, including which headers are included to support that private code.

So, the inclusion is redundant at the time it's done, but that's done in the expectation that it might stop being redundant as `idiot.h` evolves.

This best-practice model is not automatically enforced - you have to understand the way this should work and actively code to that model.

#### Example

If `idiot.h` contains...

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
...
class X {
    void add(const std::string&);
  private:
    std::vector<std::string> v_;
};
```

...then `bonito.cpp` can reasonably use `std::string` without including `<string>`, but should include `<vector>` itself if it needs `std::vector<>`.

Comment: Thanks. It was kinda funny reading this well-written answer with my stupid filenames lol